# Grpc parallel Stream communication leads to error:AkkaNettyGrpcClientGraphStage

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-grpc

I have two services: one that sends stream data and the second one receives it using akka-grpc for communication. When source data is provided Service one is called to process and send it to service two via grpc client. It's possible that multiple instances of server one runs at the same time when multiple source data are provided at the same time.In long running test of my application. I see below error in service one:

```
ERROR i.a.g.application.actors.DbActor - GraphStage [akka.grpc.internal.AkkaNettyGrpcClientGraphStage$$anon$1@59d40805] terminated abruptly, caused by for example materializer or act
  akka.stream.AbruptStageTerminationException: GraphStage [akka.grpc.internal.AkkaNettyGrpcClientGraphStage$$anon$1@59d40805] terminated abruptly, caused by for example materializer or actor system termination.
```

I have never shutdown actor systems but only kill actors after doing their job. Also I used `proto3` and `http2` for request binding. Here is a piece of my code in service one:

```
////////////////////server http binding /////////
 val service: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] =
  ServiceOneServiceHandler(new ServiceOneServiceImpl(system))

val bound = Http().bindAndHandleAsync(
  service,
  interface = config.getString("akka.grpc.server.interface"),
  port = config.getString("akka.grpc.server.default-http-port").toInt,
  connectionContext = HttpConnectionContext(http2 = Always))

bound.foreach { binding =>
  logger.info(s"gRPC server bound to: ${binding.localAddress}")
}

////////////////////client /////////
def send2Server[A](data: ListBuffer[A]): Future[ResponseDTO] = {
val reply = {

      val thisClient = interface.initialize()
      interface.call(client = thisClient, req = data.asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[StoreRequest]].toList)

  }
  reply
}

///////////////// grpc communication //////////
def send2GrpcServer[A](data: ListBuffer[A]): Unit = {
val reply = send2Server(data)
Await.ready(reply, Duration.Inf) onComplete {
  case util.Success(response: ResponseDTO) =>
    logger.info(s"got reply message: ${res.description}")

    //////check response content and stop application if desired result not found in response
    }
  case util.Failure(exp) =>
    //////stop application
    throw exp.getCause
}
```

}

Error occurred exactly after waiting for service 2 response :

```
Await.ready(reply, Duration.Inf)
```

I can't catch the cause of error.

**UPDATE**

I found that some stream is missed such that service one sends an stream an indefinitely wait for the response and service two does not receive any thing to reply to service one but still don't know why stream is missed 
I also updated akka grpc plugin but has no sense:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "0.6.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.4")
```